# child_process.execFile is not working with phantomjs and highcharts-convert.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, phantomjs, child-process

I've written a nodejs program for generating highcharts image.It looks like this.

```
var phantom = require('phantomjs');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var childArgs = [
    '/usr/bin/Export/highcharts-convert.js',
    '-infile',
    '/usr/bin/infile.json',
    '-outfile',
    '.png',
    '-constr',
    'Chart',
    '-callback',
    '/usr/bin/callback.js'
];
childProcess.execFile(phantom.path, childArgs, null, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
}
```

Here, I am getting the stdout as empty string.

But When I execute the same command from terminal, I'm getting the png output on the console.
**From terminal:**

```
/usr/bin/Export/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/Export/highcharts-convert.js -infile /usr/bin/infile.json -outfile .png -constr Chart -callback /usr/bin/callback.js
```

By executing this command on terminal, I'm getting the png output. But when i run the program, i'm getting empty string in the stdout. So is there any additional configuration to be made ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the output of ```console.log(phantom.path);```?

Comment: did you manage to make it work? I'm in a similar situation now and looking for a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, was anyone able to find a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting timeout from 30000 to **0**, worked for me. It takes a bit of time for the phantom script to execute,

```
childProcess.execFile(phantomjs.path, args, {timeout: 0 }, function(outErr, stdout, stderr) {})
```

Can you check your timeout value?